# Solr: Mapping search words to filter

Tags: solr

I'm creating a search engine based on Solr 4.3.0.
My users should be allowed to enter location (e.g. New York) in the same searchfield like they enter the other searchkeywords (e.g. restaurant).
I have a list of possible locations.
Can I catch the locations and map them to a field?
In the end, I like to show a link: "You set the location to New York, if you like to remove the filter, click on New York". The latter would be standard in Solr - but I have no approach for the mapping ...

Comment: You want to take all possible values for location field and display it on UI?

Comment: No, e.g. a user searches for "New York". I want to catch "New York" now. The "normal" behaviour of solr qould be to send q=restaurant New York. I want Solr to send: q=restaurant&fq:locationField=New York instead

Comment: So, you wants user to enter their location and then apply fq?
If yes, this is what you want, I can't understand your problem. Just read location and create SolrQuery with fq param equal to something like NY

Comment: yes, but where to read the location? where's the hook? Please consider, that I want only 1 searchfield at all, for all possible keywords ...

Comment: oh, i see. you need concept search, i guess :) in our company we just recently run teaser of concept search. Let me write possible approach in the answer

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach (without concept search) is to generate all possible queries like that

SearchBox="cafe san francisco"

And you should create query something like this

```
   BooleanQuery
       Occur1 q=cafe&fq=san
       Occur2 q=cafe san&fq=francisco
       Occur3 q=cafe san francisco&fq=empty
       ...
       OccurN q=cafe&fq=san francisco
       ...
       etc
```

And place all them as Occur.SHOULD
So, you will have a lot of near-miss results, but at least it should work as a starting approach for you.

Related articles/documentation

http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html - take a look about BooleanQuery
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_search - overall about concept search (It will be the best solution for you, but it's will be much harder to implement)